# Why fs.writeFile is not working on windows

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I am trying to write a file to window location using node js fs node module with path generating on runtime
Below code is not working

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
fs.writeFile(path.join(MediaPath,filepath), buffer, { flag: 'w' }, function (err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

The following code is working:

```
fs.writeFile("E:\\Workspace\\All_Important\\asd\\df\\df\\asda\\dD\\ci\\RMGQK710DHRQ68RQ577.yty", buffer, { flag: 'w' }, function (err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: file is not getting created if i use path join else with hardcoded string path it is working